# Giving a captionless figure the correct figure number

Tags: numbering, captions

I have a document containing two figures, and the first one is to have no kind of \caption{} in it at all but it should be numbered as though it is Figure 1. If I just omit it, then the next figure (which does have a \caption{}) gets numbered as if it is Figure 1, even though it should really be Figure 2. How do I fix this?

Comment: Add a caption, where's the problem?

Comment: `\stepcounter{figure}`?

Comment: @TeXnician, can you put that as an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `\stepcounter{figure}` in place of the caption you want to omit. This will increase the figure number as a `\caption` would do (okay, not fully, as you would need `\refstepcounter` for labeling, but the normal version should suffice).

Comment: It's still unclear to me how a reader can find figure 1.

Comment: @egreg I agree. But if the OP wishes to confuse the reader...